# How to print c_type byte array as set of hexadecimal values in python?

Tags: python, hex

I have data structure defined as follows:

```
class Factory_Params_Get_Command(Structure):
_pack_ = 1
_fields_ = [("SN",c_byte * 32),
            ("Voltage",c_byte),
            ("Reserved",c_byte * 30)]
# Print the fields
def __str__(self):
    return "Serial Number: %s"  % (list(self.SN))
```

This prints the serial number like:

```
[0, 32, 58, 73.....]
```

I would like to print the serial number as set of hexadecimal values, where each byte is represented by 2 hex numbers, and , if possible , without commas and without spaces. Something like this:

```
03C8A0D6.....
```

Would appreciate your help

Comment: Have you tried `hex(number)` function?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly something like:

```
hexstring = ''.join('%02X' % b for b in self.SN)
```

That applies the formatting string `%02X` to every byte in the array, and then concatenates everything into a single string.  For example:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> sn = (ctypes.c_byte*32)(*range(1,32))
>>> hexstring = ''.join('%02X' % b for b in sn)
>>> print hexstring
0102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F101112131415161718191A1B1C1D1E1F00
>>>
```